# PHP automated emails with OWA over HTTPS

Tags: php, email, https, outlook-web-app

I want to write a script for a web app that sends automated confirmation/notification emails. I had it working with PHP mailer and gmail but I now need to do it for Outlook using OWA over HTTPS. Also the email needs to send an attached pdf document generated using fpdf and an uploaded file. The data for the attachments is from a MySQL server. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Also if you guys know another way to do it using another programming language please let me know but keep in mind it should be able to be integrated with the rest of the scripts since I have about 60-70 php scripts and this is the last one... Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Exchange Web Services (EWS). See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene and thanks for the tip. I've taken a look at that and from what I can see its for C#. Would it be easy to just just write the C# code for the email part and then just call that script from PHP whenever I would like to send emails?

Comment: It is up to you. Can't give you any valuable advice because I am not a PHP developer.